# Copy an item from one 2d array to a different 2d array: Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2d grid of labels in which I want to grow a graph. The root is colored blue and randomly positioned, subsequent leaves, are firstly green and then red. Each red label will in the next growth cycle add a further two leaves to the graph.

I would like to keep the parent copies in a separate 2d array, any advice on how to achieve this.

```
int xPos, yPos;
xPos = ROW;
yPos = COL;
Random randomCell = new Random();
xPos = randomCell.nextInt( ROW );
yPos = randomCell.nextInt( COL );


if ( !Color.blue.equals(label[xPos][yPos].getBackground())) {
     label[xPos][yPos].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
}
```

The `label[][] blue` is what I want to place in a separate `parent[][]`.

During further cycles the parent[][] will be red.

Comment: what are the diemensions of the array?

Comment: The dimensions are x = 49 and y = 49. These are cells which can each hold a single graph node. I have been using a smaller grid for initial steps but I think that I probably wont want to be bigger than some factor of nine such as 81.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is. Can you describe your algorithm further? You've explained clearly the selection of the root node, but not what happens later.

You could also clarify what problems do you find with having a separate parent - creating another 2D array is simple, right?

Comment: you want to save only the labels that have blue color?
so you can create a vector or list.. and in your if statement put the label into the list or the vector

Comment: What I want to save are the coordinates of the tile defined by xPos and yPos which I then go on to use in the growth algorithm. The first node in the graph being drawn is coloured blue. grow some children and colour them green. At the next growth cycle convert the crop of children into parents and then grow a further crop of children.

Comment: I have solved this in a different way by placing the xChild and yChild into two separate arraylists and i can then copy each to the xParent and yParent. At the end of each growth cycle the child coordinates are passed to the parents and discarded. The new parents then grow a further layer of child nodes.

Comment: I am having a problem entering the code to show you.